# GAE Memcache Usage for NDB Seems Low

Tags: google-app-engine, memcached, app-engine-ndb

I have a Google App Engine project with a ~40 GB database, and I'm getting poor read performance with NDB. I've noticed that my memcache size (as listed on the dashboard) is only about 2 MB. I would expect NDB to implicitly make more use of memcache to improve performance.

Is there a way of debugging NDB's memcache usage?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question is rather poorly formulated -- there are a zillion reasons for poor read performance, and most are due to a poorly written app, but you don't tell us anything about the app.

The only question that can be answered is the final one: "Is there a way of debugging NDB's memcache usage?"  In addition to Sologoub's pointers I'd suggest using Appstats to find out whether the expected memcache calls are actually being made.  And reading the NDB source code, especially get() and put() in context.py, might also help.

Comment: Guido; all the models are set to use memcache and we see the calls being made in appstats. The real question is why is there only 2MB and 250 items in memcache -- it seems that items are being evicted - what is the memory, item #, or time limit? The oldest item is 12 hours, despite writing new models all the time, and the total number of cacheable entities written in even the past hour is much greater than 250.

Comment: There are no hard limits on item count and memory usage, and these numbers seem low. Maybe your app isn't using memcache enough for the memcache server to bother to retain your items -- it favors apps and items with a high hit rate. Also: (a) if you aren't using @ndb.toplevel right it is possible that you are not actually writing the values to memcache; (b) values are only written to memcache when you *get* them (put just *clears* them). So if you're not reading them back it is understandable that they aren't in the cache; and the cache is only effective for the 2nd and subsequent read.

Answer (score 1):

This page does a good job explaining how NDB caching works:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/cache

The first place I'd check would be the policy settings to make sure that you are in fact telling NDB to cache what you want cached: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/cache#policy_functions